# Does JavaScript or jQuery have a function similar to Excel's VLOOKUP?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do JavaScript or jQuery have a function that returns the element of an array whose index equal to the position of a given value in another array? (I could write my own, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.)

Something like:

```
function vlookup(theElement, array1, array2) {
    $.each(array1, function(index, element) {
        if (element === theElement)
            return array2[index];
    });
    return null;
}
```

But, um... in the standard library.

Comment: Your example doesn't look like [the typical vlookup usage](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php), but what's wrong with coding it yourself?

Comment: I dislike coding something I could code not. Since I'm such a sloppy idiot, I prefer using actually designed/tested standard libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Array.prototype.vlookup = function(needle,index,exactmatch){
    index = index || 0;
    exactmatch = exactmatch || false;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        var row = this[i];

        if ((exactmatch && row[0]===needle) || row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
            return (index < row.length ? row[index] : row);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can use it against a double array, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/9b2XF/)

Depending your purpose, you can modify the `indexOf` to make both strings lowercase first so the comparison doesn't fail with "foo" vs "FOO". Note also that if `index` exceeds the row's length, the entire row is returned (this can be changed to the first element (or whatever) easily by modifying the `: row);` portion.